# Regex that can match these conditions

Tags: c#, regex

I can't seem to figure out a regex that matches what I need. I need it to match the part with the brackets like `"TNT"` as long as the line doesn't contain DONT_TRANSLATE

> AddItem("TNT", false, true, true, false);//DONT_TRANSLATE < Shouldn't match
>
> AddItem("Flower", false, true, true, false); < Should match

It is not always replacing text in functions, so stuff such as

> cout << "Text requiring translation";
>
> itemInfo += "Text";
>   needs to also match the regex.

This is what I have currently but it's not working properly.

```
void TranslationReplace(string english, string chinese, ref string fullText)
{
    Regex translationRegex = new Regex('"' + Regex.Escape(english) + "\"(?!DONT_TRANSLATE)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    fullText = translationRegex.Replace(fullText, "\"" + chinese + "\"");
}
```

Comment: this is the complete wrong way to handle translation in .net.

Comment: It's a C# program that translates my c++ source code from another program. It's not for translation in .NET .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you only need the text between quotes then this will look for it and will ignore any line that contain any thing after it with //DONT_TRANSLATE included

```
".*"(?!.*\/\/DONT_TRANSLATE)
```

[RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/wLcc46/5)

Comment: It won't match every case. Updated my post to give a bit more info.